# How to Solve the Failed to initialize the CLR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I Have a Following Error ..

> Failed to initialize the Common Language Runtime (CLR) v4.0.30319 with
>   HRESULT 0x80004005. You need to restart SQL Server to use CLR
>   integration features.

How To Fix This Error ..

Comment: The message says you need to restart SQL Server. Have you already done that? Have you tried anything else?

Comment: Yes ,  I Restart This SQL Service only , Then Automatically Clear This Error...

Answer (score 2):

You could have a bad / incomplete install of .NET 4 (I have seen it happen at least once). Try downloading and running the following repair utility from Microsoft to see if it can fix the problem:

[Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2698555/microsoft-net-framework-repair-tool-is-available)

Answer (score 0):

Is this a new instance setup? 
Have you previously enabled CLR on the instance?

You can check by running the following commands:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
sp_configure;
GO
```

Look at the parameter "clr enabled", and under the 'Run Value' if it showed '0', it means that it has not been enabled.

To enable the paramater "clr enabled":

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Then restart the SQL Server service in order for the parameter to take effect.

Comment: Just FYI: `clr enabled` is not an "advanced" option. Meaning: you don't need the `sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO`.